# Resize iframe height on local page when remote page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've followed the advice [here](http://solidgone.org/Set-IFRAME-height-based-on-size-of-remotely-loaded-content) and gotten it to work as it should. However, it doesn't accomplish *exactly* what I'm after. I'm pulling in a form from another url, and when the user submits the form it serves up a confirmation page. Is there any sort of way to dynamically check when a page reload has occurred inside the iframe, and then in real time (I'd assume using AJAX) update the height of it to reflect the new calculated height of the confirmation page?

I'm guessing this is not doable, but I wanted to check :)

Comment: Is the iframe URL in the same domain as the parent page?

Comment: You could use the technique described [here](http://onlineaspect.com/uploads/postmessage/parent.html) to do cross-browser communication between iframes on different domains. The gist of is is that you set up an event listener on the parent page that waits for a window.postMessage call from the child page(iframe). When it receives this message it adjust the height of the iframe. I've used this code in a production environment and it works great.

Comment: Okay so I would insert that script onto the parent page, and then would have to tie it it in to the scripts I already have from that solidgone tutorial. According to the tutorial I linked to above, would the event listener need to be placed in remote.html or helper.html? I'mn not exactly a javascript expert yet :/